# Creating variables from Python dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a container class for urls and their headers, Resource:

```
class Resource(object):
    def __init__(self, url, headers):
        self.url = url
        self.content-length = headers['content-length']
        self.content-type = headers['content-type']

        # etc....
```

The `headers` argument to the `__init__` method expects a dict returned from the `getinfo()` method of `urllib2.urlopen()`. I thought this would be a more readable way of packaging up the resource url and headers. Typing `self.someheader = headers['someheader']` over and over made me wonder if there's some way to automate creating variables from dictionary keys like this. Is this possible?

Comment: That is not valid Python! If you realize that, you also realize why it's impossible to do this for general dicts.

Comment: This is sort of dangerous. Like PHP automatic variables.

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz what makes it dangerous? Does it create some kind of security issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python identifiers can't have the `-` symbol in them! So we can replace it with `_` in the keys.
Changing the keys to lowercase makes them look like a conventional variable name, and, what is very important, removes uppercase/lowercase confusion (because headers are usually sent with capitalized keys).

```
for k, v in headers.items():
    setattr(self, k.lower().replace('-', '_'), v)
```

If you're using Python 2, `iteritems` is better here, as it doesn't create a new list of items, but just lets you iterate over them, which Python 3 does by default.

It may be a good idea to store those keys in a "private" *dict* (e. g. `self._headers`). Then you can have much more control over the process with [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) and [`__setattr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__), for example, an exception can be raised during an attempt to set an invalid key.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Yes. Well, you could remove the comment now... I edited the answer before your comment anyway.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the referral to `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`, that's a much better way of doing what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a class such as the following

```
class ADict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, field):
        return self.get(field)
```

which would then allow you to simply wrap your header in it. This would, as other people have pointed out - still not allow you to access the attributes with that include a dash, however you could use `getattr` instaed to access these attributes. Consider the following header, wrapped in `ADict`:

```
header = {'content-type': 'text/javascript', 'content-length': 30, 'accept': 'text/html'}
aheader = ADict(header)
```

Attributes such as accept can be accessed using the familiar dot-syntax whereas invalid identifier attributes can be accessed through `getattr`

```
>>>> aheader.accept
'text/html'
>>>> getattr(aheader, 'content-length')
30
```